# What surface corresponds to this representation?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that we can represent the Möbius strip by the following rectangle transformation.[image: Möbius strip]

I am very curious to know what surface would correspond, if it exists, to the following transformation.

[image: What is this?]

Comment: This is a Klein Bottle. Normally the arrows would be drawn to form a cycle but the key feature is that opposite sides reverse orientation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle

Comment: @CyclotomicField Oooh okay, I thought that the lateral arrows in opposite directions wouldn't correspond to a Klein Bottle too. Thanks!

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don't believe this is correct. Note the Wiki presentation has one pair of sides with the same orientation, the other pair reversed; not *both* reversed

Comment: "Rectangle transformation" and "representation" are somewhat unusual ways to describe these diagrams - usually in topology you would call these "gluing diagrams", and they represent certain "quotient spaces" of the closed square. These search terms might help you find more information! There is a lot of discussion to be found on the internet. (Also.. the answer depends a bit on exactly what you have in mind. Did you mean "glue the top and bottom edge, and also glue the left and right edge", or did you mean to glue them *all* together?)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks for the clarification!!! I didn't know the answer depends on what I had in mind… Could you tell me the difference between both meanings, please?

Comment: I mean that being pedantic, the natural way to interpret your diagram is "glue the left side to the top side, then glue the right side to the top side, then glue the bottom side to the top side", rather than "glue the left side to the right side, then glue the top side to the bottom side". Could you confirm that you're interested in the second one? FShrike's answer below addresses that. The second one is the one that topologists care about the most so it's tempting to assume that's what you're asking. Usually the diagram for that would make clear that there are two distinct pairs of arrows.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I see. I really didn't know there was that distinction, I asked because I was curious, but I am interested in the most important, so the second one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not the Klein bottle. It "is" $\Bbb RP^2$.

I'm no artist, but here's "all" the classics:

[image: Quotient squares]

Your one is equivalent to the bottom right. Sorry I can't draw $\Bbb RP^2$ ;)

I guess in light of the surprising popularity of this answer, I should say a few words about why what I've claimed to be correct is actually correct.

> The cylinder $S^1\times I$: intuitively, bend the sheet of card so the top edge meets the bottom edge, you'll just get a tube. Formally map a point $(x,y)$ of the square to $(\exp(2\pi iy),x)$. This is a continuous surjection $I\times I\to S^1\times I$, with the domain space compact and the codomain space Hausdorff, so it must be an open map; in particular, it is a quotient map. Going for a different theorem of topology, it's a quotient map because it's the product of the quotient map $I\twoheadrightarrow S^1$ with the compact Hausdorff space $I$ and it is known that products with compact Hausdorff spaces preserve quotients (indeed, define a cocontinuous functor). And the relation it induces in the quotient is precisely the one we expect; $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$. This is encoded by the lines; the top edge is identified with the bottom.

I will not say any more about the use of compactness principles to infer the maps are quotient maps, but it is used all the time!

> The torus $S^1\times S^1$: bend the card as in the cylinder construction, but now you need to make the circular faces at the left and right ends of the cylinder meet. Doing this (with equal orientation, as per the arrows) gives you a torus in the classical doughnut shape. Formally, just use $(x,y)\mapsto(\exp(2\pi ix),\exp(2\pi iy))$ as your quotient map.

> The Mobius strip and Klein bottle: eh well, how to "prove" these ones will entirely depend on your definition. You could take these identification squares as the definition...
>
> Visually, the Mobius strip is best understood by squeezing the square along the horizontal axis (so it really is thin, like a strip) and then fixing the base edge, moving the top edge around in a circle until it meets the bottom - but you need to introduce a twist somewhere in this circular rotation in order to enforce the opposite orientations that the arrows dictate. You can actually do this one with paper and glue, or tape.
>
> [image: Mobius image]
>
> The Klein bottle; imagine you're forming the torus and you've a cylinder with the two circular faces. You want to move the rightmost face around in a loop so that it can come back to meet the bottom face, but you can't do this and also reverse orientation at the same time (twisting it doesn't work). You'll realise you need to turn one of the circular faces around and then stick them together *without making any more turns*, which is not possible in physical space; you have to push the face through the cylinder somehow without actually passing through the cylinder. Hence the classic Klein bottle depiction.
>
> [image: Klein image]

> For $\Bbb RP^2$: there is a homeomorphism of the square and disc, $x\mapsto\|x\|_\infty x/\|x\|$ (this just squishes the square down to the inscribed circle, moving points by differing amounts according to their 'size'). Up to a re-speeding parametrisation, the identifications imposed on the square correspond to identifications of a half-arc with its reflected half-arc, $z\sim-z$. This is exactly the quotient that describes $\Bbb RP^2$ as per the usual definition.
>
> [image: Projective plane image]

Comment: Amazing! But I notice some difference between the bottom right and mine. It is the same although your left arrow points up and your right arrow points down?

Comment: @galoisman The arrows are a visual aid. What we are really saying is this: for points on opposing edges, $(0,t)\sim(1,1-t)$ and $(t,0)\sim(1-t,1)$. This is conveyed by both my picture and yours; how you draw the arrow doesn't matter, just so long as they have opposite direction.

Comment: "Sorry I can't draw $\Bbb RP^2$" I don't think many can. It's the one space I never saw drawn in my algebraic topology class, and presumably for good reason. (Although rumor has it that one of the hats of the pirate jesters on the front cover of [Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 1"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/211192.A_Comprehensive_Introduction_to_Differential_Geometry_Vol_1) is meant to be a projective plane.)

Comment: @Arthur Of course any not-immersable-in-3D space has only a glimmer of a hope of being drawn. We are lucky with the Klein bottle. I’m pretty sure I’ve seen suggestive sketches of the projective plane before, and one of ‘my’ professors, André Henriques, made a stunning cardboard model of $\Bbb RP^2$ by hand. Pretty cool; shame I can’t remember quite what it looks like

Comment: @galoisman I've added some more visuals

Comment: @FShrike I love it, this is fascinating! :D

Comment: Related.The Spinor Spanner: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318771

Comment: @EthanBolker Nice!

Comment: My best-scoring answer ever was a picture! Great job.